# _highScore.text not updating when the game is over

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

**UIManager.cs:** My high score is not updating when the game is over.
In `start` method I get the previous high score and in `CheckForHighScore` method if current score > previous score then the high score will be equal to current score and save it. `CheckForHighScore` will be called in **Player.cs** script when the game is over.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class UIManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField]
    private Text _scoreText;
    [SerializeField]
    private Text _highScoreText;

    public int currentScore;
    public int highScore;

    void Start()
    {
        _scoreText.text = "Score: " + 0;
        highScore = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("HighScore", 0);
        _highScoreText.text = "High Score: " + highScore;
    }

    public void UpdateScore()
    {
        currentScore+=10;
        _scoreText.text = "Score: " + currentScore.ToString();
    }

    public void CheckForHighScore()
    {
        if(currentScore > highScore)
        {
            highScore = currentScore; // if I debug.log here then it shows the high score correctly
            PlayerPrefs.SetInt("HighScore", highScore);
            _highScoreText.text = "High Score: " + highScore; // but here in the text it does not update
        }
    }
    
    public void GameOver(){
      _gameOverText.gameObject.SetActive(true);
      _restartText.gameObject.SetActive(true);
      StartCoroutine(FlickerRoutine());
      _gameManager.GameOver();
    }
// I have removed the methods that are not related to the score
}
```

**Player.cs:**

```
if (_lives < 1)
{
    _UIManager.CheckForHighScore(); // chech high score method from UIManager is called here
    _spawnManager.onPlayerDeath();
    _UIManager.GameOver();
    Destroy(this.gameObject);
}
```

Comment: What does happen in `_UIManager.GameOver();`?

Comment: public void GameOver(){
        _gameOverText.gameObject.SetActive(true);
        _restartText.gameObject.SetActive(true);
        StartCoroutine(FlickerRoutine());
        _gameManager.GameOver();

    }

Comment: I removed it because it became lengthy here.

Comment: ok then what does `_gameManager.GameOver();` do? The question is: is it possible that the correct text is there for a moment but then something else happens which resets the text somehow?

Comment: ```public void GameOver(){
        _isGameOver = true;
 }``` it sets _isGameOver to true

Comment: yeah but I mean ... we don't know your project ... so what does this mean? what happens after game over? E.g. do you change the scene, do you disable enable parts of the UI... etc

Comment: so ```_gameManager.GameOver()``` sets ```_isGameOver = true``` because when the game is over player might want to restart the game so player has to press **R** key to restart. So the R has to work only when game is over so this ```_isGameOver``` variable is used to check it. ```if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.R) && _isGameOver == true){ SceneManager.LoadScene(0); }``` so it restarts the game.

Answer (score 0):

Reading your problem description and the comments below it, I supose that you are not saving the highscore anywhere in order to maintain it during the scene switch.
Maybe the correct way to keep the highscore is having a component assigned to an object only to handle this value which you [don't destroy on load](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.DontDestroyOnLoad.html) or you could also save that value in [PlayerPrefs](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/PlayerPrefs.html) which also works, but maybe is not the proper use of this utility.

Answer (score 0):

Try using *.ToString();* to convert your highScore interger value to string as *+* operator will add two variable if they are numbers and if they are strings they will try to join.
Or
Just save the highScore value as String as *PlayerPerfs.SetString("HighScore", "highScore");* and if you are useing this method then just change the type to string of variable highScore.